# Display label & block if associated product count is greater than 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am running Magento 1.9.1 and I have created a block to display a "More Colours" label on the category page in each product's block but I would like this label to only display when the associated (simple) product count for the configurable product is greater than 1. In other words, if more than one colour is available; show the "More Colours" label.

I tried the below code, with the first if statement being the code I added to the original file in order to accomplish this, but to no avail, if anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appeciated.

```
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());    
<?php 
$usedProductIds = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
if(count($usedProductIds)>1);?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
<dl>
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <dt id="label-<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>-<?php echo $_product->getEntityId() ?>"><label class="more-colours">More Colours</label></dt>
    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box" style="margin: 2px;">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>-<?php echo $_product->getEntityId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select-<?php echo $_product->getEntityId() ?>">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div id="requared-attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>-<?php echo $_product->getEntityId() ?>" style="color:red"></div>
    </dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    optionsPrice['<?php echo $_product->getId();?>'] = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getPriceJsonConfig();?>);
</script>
```

Comment: How did you get `$_attributes`?

Comment: Edited original post, does this help? I am not a PHP developer so my knowledge is extremely limited! Thanks

Comment: Then you should a look at this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11498/4848 . It contains detailed code. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: What error are you getting?